# Unable to use include filters in remote methods

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have been using include filters in remote hooks like in a login hook and they work like a charm:

```
customer.afterRemote('login', function(ctx, modelInstance, next) {
      if (ctx.result) {
          customer.find({include: ['someRelationA', 'someRelationB', 'someRelationC'], where: {id: ctx.result.userId}}, function(err, obj) {
            next();
          });
      }
      else{
          next();
      }
    });
```

But when I am using include filters in a remote method, like this:

```
customer.getProfile = function (userId, cb) {
      customer.find({include: ['someRelationA', 'someRelationB', 'someRelationC'], where: {id: userId}}, function(err, obj) {
            // commonHelper.setFinalObject(ctx, obj);
            cb(err, obj);
          });
    };
```

They won't get very well, receiving following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "MongoError",
    "status": 500,
    "message": "not authorized for query on mytestdb.someRelationA",
    "$err": "not authorized for query on mytestdb.someRelationA",
    "code": 13,
    "stack": "MongoError: not authorized for query on mytestdb.someRelationA ..."
  }
}
```

My Remote hook declaration is as follows:

```
customer.getProfile = function (userId, cb) {
      customer.find({include: ['someRelationA', 'someRelationB', 'someRelationC'], where: {id: userId}}, function(err, obj) {
            cb(err, obj);
          });
    };

    customer.remoteMethod(
        'getProfile',
        {
            accepts: {arg: 'id', type: 'string', required: true},
            returns: {type: 'object', root: true},
            http: {path: '/:id/getprofile', verb: 'get'}
        }
    );
```

Note: If I remove include filter and only use customer.findById the user object is returned successfully, but its due to some ACL issue that I am not able to use include filters. Any help is highly appreciated.

UPDATE: Refreshing the request twice or thrice returns things as expected, and then it runs successfully onwards, I am guessing its some caching and querying delay that is required first time, after relations are built, records are returned successfully.

Comment: It seems to be mongo side, not loopback ACL. Do you run mongo with auth?

Comment: You can try to get more information by enabling debug strings (https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Setting+debug+strings). In particular maybe enabling "loopback:connector:mongodb" to see if the query is being created correctly or possibly "strong-remoting:*" to see what's going on on the remoting framework.